# influxdb ***v2*** query requesting microseconds-since-epoch timestamp

Tags: api, influxdb, epoch

When I query the influxdb v2 using the /api/v2/query api, timestamps are returned in RFC3339 format - something that is ridiculously slow to parse back into a useful timestamp.  Influxdb v1.x used to allow the specification of seconds/microseconds/nanoseconds since epoch.  How does one do this in v2?

xx

Answer (score 0):

My approach is converting datetime to uint. It won't take much time, faster than parsing RFC3339 on client side, as InfluxDB 2.0 API Documentation doesn't provide a way to print epoch.

```
|> map(fn: (r) => ({r with epoch_ms: uint(v: r._time) / uint(v: 1000000)}))
|> drop(columns: ["_start", "_stop", "_time"])
```

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.1/api/#operation/PostQuery